# angular 5, reactive form- resetting a required form control does not reset the required error under the input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

In the template I have a form that is opened by pressing on a button-

```
     <form [formGroup]="person"
          (ngSubmit)="onSubmitNewPerson()"
          #formDirective="ngForm">

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="firstName" required>
            </mat-form-field>

            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput formControlName="lastName" #last required>
            </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

In the component I have this code-

```
  @ViewChild('formDirective') formDirective: FormGroupDirective;

 this.person = this.formBuilder.group({
            lastName: ['', Validators.required],
            firstName: ['', Validators.required]
        });
```

After closing the button I run this function-

```
   this.formDirective.resetForm();//hack that I saw in some question
    this.person.reset();
```

but after openning again the form, I immediatly see the red error under the input.

I also tried this-

```
    this.person.get('firstName').markAsUntouched();
   this.person.get('lastName').markAsUntouched();
     this.person.get('firstName').markAsPristine();
    this.person.get('lastName').markAsPristine();
```

But this does not work also.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to remove `required` from your html template ?

Comment: But I want the affect of the red line under the input when the focus is out.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce, please create a [mcve] Best would be a stackblitz :)

Comment: remove required from html template

Answer (score 2):

I used the following once when I wanted to reset the validators:

```
    this.person.get('firstName').clearValidators();
    this.person.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove required from your html template and if you want to display error message on focus out than try this to show different error message.

this is html template:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="form-control-label">
        *Amount:
        </label>
        <input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control"  [formControl]="form.controls['amount']">
        <div>
        <small *ngIf="form.controls['amount'].hasError('required') && form.controls['amount'].touched" class="text-danger">
           Please enter an amount.
        </small>
        <small  *ngIf="form.controls['amount'].hasError('min') && form.controls['amount'].touched" class="text-danger">
             Your amount must be at least 0.01.
        </small>
        <small  *ngIf="form.controls['amount'].hasError('max') && form.controls['amount'].touched" class="text-danger">
                Your amount cannot exceed 999999.99.
        </small>
        </div>
```

This is component.ts

```
 import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {  }

this.form = this.fb.group({
    amount: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.min(0.01), Validators.max(999999.99)])],
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is slightly old,
This answer may help people who have this issue.

If this problem occurs in the Angular material `mat-stepper`, you can see the solution offered for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51368437/8994917).

(That why some respondents were unable to reproduce the problem)