# Prevent a new formControl to be invalid after a mat-stepper is complete

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

I'm using mat-stepper component of Angular Material, as a multi-form steps.

I'd like to prevent the following behaviour:

1. Step 1 is valid
2. User moves on step 2
3. User goes back on step 1
4. User adds a control (e.g adding a formArray item)
5. The new item is already invalid (red) even if it's untouched/pristine.

Why is the new item already invalid? I've noticed it has already a mat-form-field-invalid class...

[Here is the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-stepper-array?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstepper-overview-example.html)

Any hints? Thanks!

Comment: Only solution which comes to my mind is to override material styles with your own and I'd work with ng-invalid/ng-touched instead of mat-form-field-invalid

Answer (score 0):

What [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51410530/9138818) says is that validation is running on the full step form whenever a step has been "interacted".

So a workaround for your case would be to add the control without any validator (nor required attribute in the template), and to set them whenever the user goes to another step (with the MatStepper [selectionChange](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api#MatStepper) output).