mat-form-field validation messages dispalying before any user interaction

Here is the code for reference,
  <div>
      <mat-form-field class="w-100 mt-2" appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Enter a name for your quote</mat-label>

        <input #quoteName matInput placeholder="Enter a name for your quote" formControlName="quoteName" [maxlength]="40"  (input)="onQuoteNameInput($event)" />
        <mat-hint align="end">{{quoteName.value.length}} / 40</mat-hint>
        <mat-error *ngIf="quoteDetailsFormGroup.controls.quoteName.touched && quoteDetailsFormGroup.controls.quoteName.errors?.required">Quote Name is
          required.</mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>

In the code above, I am using the touched property to control the display of error messages, so I can successfully show or hide them as needed. However, the input field's outline border still appears red as soon as the form loads. How can I prevent the red outline from appearing initially?

Not reproducible in the examples from docs. Are you using a custom errorStateMatcher?

No, I have not used a custom ErrorStateMatcher.

can you please share stacblitz link with you code so I can get a better idea

Thank you for your response! Since this project is part of my organization’s codebase, I can’t share it directly. I believe the issue may be related to the Angular Material Stepper, as we’re using it in our project. I also referred to this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368437/angular-material-stepper-causes-mat-formfield-to-validate-for-dynamic-forms-when but unfortunately, it didn’t resolve the issue

Check your conditions
*ngIf="quoteDetailsFormGroup.controls.quoteName.touched && quoteDetailsFormGroup.controls.quoteName.errors?.required"


There is no issue with condition.
